React App with FullCalendar integrating with Outlook and Task planner
How to perform two sync between react front end application with Microsoft outlook calendar.
Tasks should be able to added from both the ends like Outlook as well as react end.
1.Add a task from UI and verify it is appearing in the outlook Calendar
2.Add a task from Task Planner and verify it is appearing in  the Calendar UI

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Does your React application have a backend associated with it? e.g. somewhere that you store the event/task data which is added to the calendar? Perhaps it involves a database, maybe? This sounds more like a broad architecture / feature-design question than a specific programming issue though, which is not something we generally deal with at Stackoverflow. There are other stackexchange sites I believe where you can ask more architecture-oriented question. For stackoverflow usage, please take the [tour], and read [ask] and its linked articles, then you have a better idea what a good post is.
